# OCaml match on string option ref

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

How do I do a pattern match on a variable that has type `string option ref` in OCaml. I need to extract the string part of this variable, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ref` is just a record type with a mutable field called `contents`:

```
type 'a ref = { mutable contents: 'a }
```

So you pattern match on it just like any other record:

```
match foo with
| { contents = Some str } -> str
| { contents = None } -> ...
```

Although I would much prefer to unwrap the `ref` first instead of matching on it:

```
match !foo with
| Some str -> str
| None -> ...
```